# Google maps marker re-add

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created some markers on google map and pushed them in an array called 'markers', I deleted them with setMap(null), but know I need to re-add those markers, but I don't know how, I have all the objects in the array.

Comment: It'd help to see your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So loop over the array, calling `marker.setMap(map);`